# JavaScript function execution on first click

Tags: javascript, html

When my index page is fully loaded, I want to run a JavaScript function when clicked anywhere. Once it works, it should no longer work. Just first boot and first click.

My function is `Website2APK.showInterstitialAd();`

My index page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clown Nights</title>
    <!-- Define the viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.01">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />

    <!-- Include the HTML5 API files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.gameplayer.io/api/js/game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.gameplayer.io/api/js/developer.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/game.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/globalconfig.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.libs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gamediv"></div>
    <!--<div id="loader"></div>-->
    <canvas id="canvas" width="720" height="480" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; display:block;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the `onload` and `onclick` functions but I couldn't.

Comment: Please add the definition of `Website2APK.showInterstitialAd`

Comment: the click listener can use `removeEventListener()` to remove it.

Comment: I'm asking how can I add it.

Comment: Use `addEventListener` with the `once` option, and attach the event to the body.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please write the whole code?

Comment: I assume "just first boot" means the first time someone ever visits the page. In that case, you could set a flag in `localStorage` and only attach the listener if the flag is not set. Or you could use a cookie instead of `localStorage` if you wanted.

Comment: this function > 'Website2APK.showInterstitialAd' it should work 1 time when clicked anywhere.

Comment: can you write the whole code?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I guess you don't know either.

Comment: @AdnanErkmen Know what either?

Comment: Please include the code you _did_ try.

Comment: Something like `document.body.addEventListener("click", () => Website2APK.showInterstitialAd(), { once: true })` should work for the first part.

Comment: I didn't add any code. i have no knowledge

Comment: thank you so much. i try this code but dont work :(

`document.body.addEventListener("click", () => Website2APK.showInterstitialAd(), { once: true })`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the triggered function and fixed the problem.

this.newGameBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
Website2APK.showInterstitialAd();});

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the event listener for `click` inside the `onload` event of `window` object. Then remove the `click` event listener inside the onclick function using `document.removeEventListener()`. It takes two arguments, first is the event-type i.e. `click` and second is the function that gets called  on firing `click` event.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => document.addEventListener('click', handleFirstClick));

function handleFirstClick() {
//add  Website2APK.showInterstitialAd(); here
  console.log('clicked');
  document.removeEventListener('click', handleFirstClick);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100dvh;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="gamediv">
  Some text!!
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much i add this but dont work

`<script>window.addEventListener('load', () => document.addEventListener('click', Website2APK.showInterstitialAd));

function handleFirstClick() {
  console.log('clicked');
  document.removeEventListener('click', Website2APK.showInterstitialAd);
}</script>`

Comment: I have added a comment in the answer where the `Website2APK.showInterstitialAd( )` should be. If you call it directly in `onClick` event it will never be removed. We are removing it inside the `handleFirstClick` function.

Comment: Adding it like this gives an error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

`<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('load', () => document.addEventListener('click', Website2APK.showInterstitialAd));

function Website2APK.showInterstitialAd() {
  console.log('clicked');
  document.removeEventListener('click', Website2APK.showInterstitialAd);
}</script>`

Comment: Obviously, it will give you error because your function definition is wrong. Tell me, what is this website2APK.showInterstitialAd( )?

Comment: I'm converting apk from html5 this code will make the interstitial appear.

Comment: ok. then just add the above javascript code to your file and simply replace the comment with `Web2APK.showinterstitial( )`

Comment: Please check that the external script that contains the`Web2APK.showInterstitial( )` is loading and not giving any error such failed to load resource..

Comment: i will try soon

Comment: thank you again. I added it like this but it doesn't work.

`<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('load', () => document.addEventListener('click', handleFirstClick));
function handleFirstClick() {
Website2APK.showInterstitialAd();
  console.log('clicked');
  document.removeEventListener('click', handleFirstClick);
} </script>`

Comment: It works when I add it like this, but I want it to work when clicked anywhere. 

`<a href="index2.html" onclick="Website2APK.showInterstitialAd();"><img alt="start-game" src="start.jpg" style="height: 96vh;max-width: 100vw;" />`

Comment: It works in my code. Do you get any error?

Comment: Do one thing add it on the body tag as  `onLoad="Website2APK.showInterstitialAd( )"`  If this doesn't work then surely there is some issue with your other scripts.

Comment: If you still have issues. Just upload the website on github and share the link. Will be way easier to debug if people had the actual code.

Comment: (index):31 Uncaught ReferenceError: Website2APK is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.handleFirstClick

Comment: can you sent my index.html + your code thanks.

Comment: This shows that the code is working. Your `Website2APK.showInterstitial()` is being called but the system is not able to find it's definition. Check the script that has this function..

Comment: thank you. i find function 

this function: `this.newGameBtn = utils.createButton(539, 320, 0.8, "playbtnup", utils.onPressStandartHandler, this.startCont, this.onPlayUp);`

I want to add Website2APK to this function.

Comment: What script are you using for showing interstitialAd? Are you using some software to convert the site to apk? What are you trying to do? You have to be more specific. This is clearly not an HTML or javascript question, you have seriously misrepresented your issue here. Either provide the code to your app or show us exactly which script contains this Website2apk object?